# IIS ReWrite remove tailing Chacters

Tags: iis

We a URL in the format... 
`http://www.portescap.com/asm?_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_h17BJzEukJakVHXKsecD9XzqCLnSo1B0bYaMP8kmTmBRNCXGKtnvdFYP7Da16cwJT8wJrrcDCWREJ2nkfnbU_KWmjBkf4NHWk794r34xlitJxNcM&_hsmi=25152208`

How do I remove everything after the first "?"  so the URL becomes
`http://www.portescap.com/asm`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a system to test this on but it should work.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="asm?(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.portescap.com/asm" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```